# C# Add custom Windows context menu for just this program

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu

My question is: How do I add a windows context menu item for a specific application, not globally?

**Quick Brief**: 
We use Access (groan) for our CRM system. We use a basic 'copy to local' process for multi-access. I have written a C# 'launcher' of which handles this much better than a .bat file (they click the launcher, the launcher downloads the db, launches the db and quits). I also currently use a C# console application to handle development, automating stuff like incrementing version number, moving files around etc.

---

**My Question/Goal**:
I want to combine the two programs into one but I don't want to hinder the launcher from it's main purpose by jarring the user asking if they want to develop or not. I use this launcher too as I am primarily an estimator, hence wanting to combine the two. I have read that you can add context menu items to Windows as a whole, but I want to be able to add a launch option into the context menu **just** for this application. i.e. right click on program, normal menu options but with the addition of "Development Mode", this opens the program with arguments that I can use to open the development window/console instead.

---

**Things to note**:

- I have played around with holding a key on start but it can be vague when to press the key. Too early - you will end up typing "r" several times into the active window, too late - and it will miss the capture point.
- I have also looked at having a button on the launcher that gives you the option to go into dev mode, but the launcher is only open for around a second so its really easy to miss.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The launcher is made and run as a click-once app.

Comment: @Anas I have amended the first line of the question to be more precise. thanks

Comment: Thanks @stuartd that's a good shout! I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to this I stumbled upon some code to make this work. Hopefully this will help someone in the future. I am doing this in WPF, but I am sure you could probably adapt this code to work elsewhere.

1) App.xaml - Adding the [JumpList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?view=netframework-4.7.2) action

After (not inside) the Application.Resources property add the following and change to your liking (There are a lot of properties I haven't used for development sake, check out the link to learn more):

```
<Application.Resources>
...
</Application.Resources>
<JumpList.JumpList>
    <JumpList ShowRecentCategory="False"
              ShowFrequentCategory="False">
        <JumpTask Title="Open Dev Mode" 
                  Description="Use this to enter dev mode (admins only)"
                  Arguments="DevMode:true"/>
    </JumpList>
</JumpList.JumpList>
```

This will create a "Task" in the jump list:

[image]

2) Create Global static class - this will allow you to store the variable for later use in other forms.

```
public static class Global
{
    public static Boolean DevMode = false;
}
```

3) App.xaml.cs - Adding [OnStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup?view=netframework-4.7.2) handler

Inside the App class create an override method for OnStartup

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Global.DevMode = Boolean.Parse(e.Args.FirstOrDefault().ToString().Split(':')[1]);
    }
}
```

4) Read the variable in your form using Global.DevMode

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Global.DevMode) RunYourDevScript();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know about whether its possible to have a custom context for a specific program, as far as i know the context works with the extension. That being said, i think there are better ways to handle your problem. Have a look at this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* here normal flow of the launcher*/

        if (args[0] == "-dev")
        {
            /*here de developer mode*/
            Console.WriteLine("Developer mode activated");
        }
    }
```

The way to use it is simple, you make a shorcut, and where it says the shorcut target you will have something like this "C:\Users****\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe" and you should change it to something like this "C:\Users****\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Test\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe" -dev

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the only issue here is that I would have to have two shortcuts for the same thing. Therefore I might as well just stick with the two applications.

Comment: I see what you mean. What if after you finish the flow of your launcher you await a number of seconds and if there is an input (any input or a specific letter perhaps) you enter the developer mode

Comment: Unfortunately the process flow of the launcher itself is to open a copy of the database. This means if I wait until the end then I will end up opening the database and going into the developer mode too. I have just had a thought of making myself a service that runs in the background, as I know that I can add a context menu to that

Comment: if you are interested... I worked out the answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55341608/7985048

Answer (score 0):

As per a suggestion in a comment, that has gone for some reason. I am going to revert to keypress but use shift instead or "R".

Failing this, or if it causes problems it will look at creating a global context menu item for all programs, and just won't click it when I don't need to